# Variable Declaration not Working

Tags: python, variables, variable-declaration

I tried to declare a variable 'join', in python, which typically only requires you to name a variable and insert some kind of value for it. When I did so, it said "invalid syntax":
(`join = 0.48` returned `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Does anyone know why it won't work?

Comment: Please post a more detailed sample of your code so that we can get an idea of the context. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a variable inside a tuple:

```
In [16]: (join = 0.48)
  File "<ipython-input-16-5ecf737095f6>", line 1
    (join = 0.48)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using:

```
In [17]: join = 0.48
In [18]: join
Out[18]: 0.48
```

works fine.

Also `join` is a `str` method so best avoided as a variable name.